Would electric shifting improve Shimano Alfine 8 ebike durability
I'm considering buying a powerful e-bike (Zen Photon Pro) and installing a Shimano Alfine 8, but I'm worried that the powerful mid drive motor might damage the hub. Would using Di2 electric shifting mitigate this risk? In addition, would the Di2 auto shift allow me to safety use the throttle without damaging the hub?
The e-bike has a 500 Watt, 120 N⋅m peak torque, mid drive motor, which is significantly more powerful than any e-bike on the market using the Alfine/Nexus 8.
Side note: I know that running an Enviolo CVT hub would be more practical. However, my experience test riding electric bikes with an Enviolo made me frustrated by the inefficiency. This inefficiency wouldn't have any practical consequences given the powerful motor and huge battery, but it would feel less fun and more emotionally frustrating. In contrast, I love how well the Alfine 8/belt combo works on my non electric bike.

A rider of the average adult male weight in the US puts more torque than that into it just with a regular standing launch.

Yes, but the 120nm of torque would be in addition to the torque from pedaling. So the total torque will be much more than 120nm.

you might want to consider Shimano Nexus. it's a little bit heavier than aline, but rated for more torque

Electric shifting can only make a difference for the wear attributable to shifting (for example to shift when the cogs are aligned as they should, if the derailleur/hub has the required tech), not on the torque applied to the system for regular use.
The manual of the Alfine Di2 indicates that you need to lower the torque when changing gears, so I would think it's mostly an electric actuation, but the Di2 doesn't provide an additional safeguard (in contrast to some recent SRAM derailleurs, that only actuate the derailleur on ramps) and it may in fact be worse, as the probability of shifting under load is higher.
Autoshift with Shimano is only available on e-bikes, and is managed at the level of the motor unit, not the derailleur/hub (by contrast to Enviolo). The justification given by Shimano is precisely because it gives them the ability to lower the torque when shifting gears. I know it's possible to connect an Alfine Di2 hub with a Bosch motor, but I doubt you'll have Autoshift with that combination (the purpose of the connection to the motor is primarily the power supply, and in some cases integration to have the current speed on the display unit).
When it comes to throttling, similar story: if the drive unit can lower the torque when gears are being changed, it should be an improvement. Otherwise the wear may be higher if you don't manually control the torque/power when you change gears.

It could be just fine, since the purpose of e-bikes is to reduce the torque needed to be generated by the cyclist. I find that on a road bike with no electric assist, I tend to sprint in an aggressive position, whereas on a road bike with electric assist, I let the motor do most of the work when accelerating, and then I exceed 25 km/h and the motor assist stops, and I use my human power for constant speed flatland riding.
Rohloff gear hub (the 14-speed one) withstands 250 newton-meters, given typical choices for chainring and sprocket sizes. Shimano doesn't specify torque ratings, but I expect them to be similar.
A cyclist can exceed 250 newton-meters when starting at standstill in a high gear, especially if you have clipless pedals. But a mid-drive motor is usually rated at something like 85 newton-meters.
Of course, with a mid-drive motor, the torque is ADDED to the cyclist torque. So a gear hub might withstand a powerful cyclist just barely, but the mid-drive motor would increase the torque to slightly above acceptable levels. But you wouldn't aggressively sprint on an e-bike anyway.
120 newton-meters is quite a lot, are you sure you need all of that? I'm fine with 50 newton-meters now that I have a regular weight, it was slightly underspecced when I was overweight.
As long as you don't sprint aggressively, 120 newton-meters is probably still less than half of what the gearhub accepts. So as long as you aren't doing more work than 50/50 power division, it won't exceed 250 newton-meters.

I have the hunch that you're writing about EU-legal pedelecs. The OP's bike has roughly 4x power and no speed or torque limiters.

It isn't power that matters, it's torque. Yes, 120 Nm is more than the 85 Nm I said as typical for the high-end EU-legal pedelecs, but still less than half of Rohloff's 250 Nm spec. Also, with a 120 Nm mid-drive motor, it's even less likely you would choose to sprint aggressively, since the motor does the work.

I’m sure you’re aware that Alfine is not Rohloff, but I feel obligated to spell it out just in case.

The Zen photon is much more powerful than I need, but it has a great combination of features I can't find elsewhere. The combination of the step through frame, belt drive, head tube mounted front rack, class 3 capabilities, throttle capability, front suspension, and a UL certified battery is what I'd ideally want from my ebike.
